# How to get the values of check boxes in a group with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a form where I added a group of check boxes like below:

```
<form action="next.php" method="get">
<input name="c1" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="c1" value="2" type="checkbox">
<input name="c1" value="3" type="checkbox">
<input name="c1" value="4" type="checkbox">
...
</form>
```

If I select the first and the 3rd check box, the URL looks good when I press the submit button, like

```
?c1=1&c1=3 [...]
```

but the $_GET array holds only the last value of c1. I know I could use the `[]` notation to get an array, but then the link looks like

```
?c1[]=1&c1[]=3 [...]
```

I saw sites that generate the URL without the `[]` and still manage to take all values into account. How do they do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Not saying you can't do it, but PHP uses the array notation. Just how it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP requires you to use a pseudo-array notation if you want to use the same fieldname for multiple different form elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1[]" ... />
<input type="checkbox" name="c1[]" ... />
<input type="checkbox" name="c1[]" ... />
etc...
```

The `[]` tells PHP to treat `c1` as an array, and keep all of the submitted values. Without `[]`, PHP will simply overwrite each previous c1 value with the new one, until the form's done processing.

Sites which don't use the `[]` notation do the form processing themselves, retrieving the query string from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and then parse it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Use have to use this:

```
<input name="c1[]" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input name="c1[]" value="2" type="checkbox">
<input name="c1[]" value="3" type="checkbox">
<input name="c1[]" value="4" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the entire querystring. You can parse the querystring into parts like so:

```
$qs = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

foreach ($qs as $part) {
    if (strpos($part,"c1") !== false) {
        $split = strpos($part,"=");
        $values[] = substr($part, $split + 1);
    }
}

var_dump($values);
```

If your querystring looks like this: ?c1=1&c1=3 the code above leaves you with a result like this:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(1) "3" 
}
```