# Unable to get all parameters from the url with $_GET in php

Tags: php

I tried to get the parameters h1 and h2 from the following url. However, when I used the code to get the values from the $_GET['params'], the print_r displayed only h2. How will I get all values "h1 and h2" ?

```
https: //localhost/mysite.com/mypage/index/?params=h1&params=h2
```

The code I tried to use for getting the parameters.

```
if(!empty($_GET['params'])){
    foreach ($_GET as $params){
     print_r($param);
    }
```

Comment: You should have both the parameters with different names.

Comment: https: //localhost/mysite.com/mypage/index/?params1=h1&params2=h2 .. you should pass variable like this.. (params1,params2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the values of check boxes in a group with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174002/how-to-get-the-values-of-check-boxes-in-a-group-with-php)

Comment: use array of  params[] ,

Answer (score 3):

PHP overwrites GET paramaters with the same name, unless you use the `[]` syntax to generate an array.

So your URL must look like this, if you want this to work in PHP:

```
...?params[]=h1&params[]=h2
```